# Python zip - extractall with utf-8 content

Tags: python, utf-8, zip

I have a problem with simple unzipping files with Python. Everything works almost fine. Problem appears when in zip archive are files with polish signs. For example: i have archive with contains Początek.txt, after unzip i get PoczÑtek.txt. Here is my code:

```
from os import listdir
import zipfile
zipdir = 'F://PYTHON_SCRIPTS//zip' 
zipy = listdir(zipdir)
for f in zipy:
    #print(zipdir+f)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipdir+'//'+f, 'r') as z:
        z.extractall('F://PYTHON_SCRIPTS//uzip')
```

Can You help me?

Here is a test file to unzip - http://jot3r.pl/testfilezip.zip

Comment: this is not an utf-8 issue. both names have the same number of characters. It is a mix up between 2 other encodings (both fixed size)

Comment: Sounds like it's a archive member filename issue not a problem with an archive member's content...correct?

Comment: @martineau - Yes it`s a archive member filename problem. In zip archive i have a simple .txt file, content of this file is ok.

Comment: @njzk2 - How can i determine it and it`s encodings? Especially encoding of txt file name, sys.getdefaultencoding() prints UTF-8.

Comment: There's some information on Zipfile filename encoding in the notes for the [`Zipfile.write()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) method. Sounds like there's no way to tell what encoding might have been used.